# printf("%-10s") works wrong in system locale

Tags: c, utf-8, locale, printf

Once i use

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); //use system locale
```

printf function does not align right. How do i align string in differnet locales?

Comment: Please post a complete example + compiler + OS that you're using

Comment: OP's question is not very clear but I think I was able to figure out the intended meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field widths cannot be used for alignment on modern multilingualized systems. Even if `printf` could count characters instead of bytes when aligning (note: the wide `printf`-family functions can do this), that will fail to accommodate for combining characters (which usually use no horizontal space) as well as CJK-wide characters (which usually use 2 columns on terminals).

The best approach I can think of is to first convert your string to a `wchar_t` string, then use `wcswidth` to determine its width in character cell columns. Then add the appropriate number of spaces before or after the field using a `%.*s` field specifier with the arguments `n` and `""` where `n` is the number of spaces you want displayed.